# Computing the center of gravity of a geoJSON Polygon using jq

Tags: bash, geometry, geojson, jq

I have a list of cities described by their polygon in geoJSON files.

I would like to get a sample inside point of the polygon.

Basic maths says the center of gravity is inside the polygon and it suffices to sum all longitudes and all latitudes together then divide it by the number of points.

[Full file to process](https://github.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson/blob/master/departements/94-val-de-marne/communes-94-val-de-marne.geojson) (visualization is available on GitHub)

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [[[2.41101, 48.72605], [2.41554, 48.72656], [2.41718, 48.72791], [2.4211, 48.72953], [2.42603, 48.72824], [2.42756, 48.72865], [2.42922, 48.72723], [2.43133, 48.72646], [2.43404, 48.72665], [2.43513, 48.72409], [2.42554, 48.7227], [2.42072, 48.72105], [2.41426, 48.71782], [2.41327, 48.71869], [2.41582, 48.72086], [2.41238, 48.72193], [2.41136, 48.72325], [2.41101, 48.72605]]]
    },
    "properties": {
      "code": "94001",
      "nom": "Ablon-sur-Seine"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [[[2.41959, 48.81691], [2.4159, 48.81633], [2.40936, 48.81667], [2.40787, 48.81746
    },
    "properties": {
      "code": "94018",
      "nom": "Charenton-le-Pont"
    }
  },
  ...
  ]
}
```

I already have a command that computes the length of the polygon vertices.

```
$ curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson/master/departements/94-val-de-marne/communes-94-val-de-marne.geojson \
> | jq '.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][][0]' \
> | jq -s 'add/length'
2.4206944444444445
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/

Using `jq` and simple bash commands, how can I compute the sum of the longitudes and sum of the latitudes as well, and reinject the barycenter in `properties` field in another geoJSON file?

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at the `bc` command line utility. You can use it to do the math in the command line

Comment: Another resource on the problem : https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc.
Still interested in just computing the center of gravity.

Comment: If you want help regarding the goal to “reinject the barycenter in properties field in another geoJSON”, please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Yes, I will update my own answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understood correctly, you're trying to get the averages of the first set of coordinates, then updating the properties to store the result.

```
.features[] |= (
    (.geometry.coordinates[0] | length as $len | reduce .[] as [$x, $y] ([0,0];
        [.[0] + $x, .[1] + $y]
    ) | map(. / $len)) as $barrycenter |
    .properties.barycenter = $barrycenter
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Where did you learn all that hard syntax from?

Comment: Hello on my dataset there are also `MultiPolygon`, how can I modify the code to handle it as well ? I would like to take `.geometry.coordinates[0][0]` or to flatMap `.geometry.coordinates`. See for example https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson/master/departements/68-haut-rhin/communes-68-haut-rhin.geojson

I think in the end I need to do to use a real scripting language to do this.

Answer (score 0):

### Warning

The "center of gravity" of a polygon is in general not the same as the point defined in terms of the averages of the x and y co-ordinates of its vertices.  See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/why-doesnt-a-simple-mean-give-the-position-of-a-centroid-in-a-polygon

### The averages of the latitudes and of the longitudes

Here is a jq filter that will,
with a single invocation of jq and without redundancy, compute the averages of the latitudes and of the longitudes of each "feature":

```
.features[].geometry.coordinates[0]
| [ [.[][0]], [.[][1]] ]
| map(add/length)
```

With the `-c` command-line option, this produces a stream of arrays, one array for each "feature".  The stream begins:

```
[2.4206944444444445,48.724651111111115]
[2.407614,48.82250133333333]
...
```

Of course there are other alternatives but note that there is no need to use string interpolation to perform grouping, so there is usually no need for `tr` as your first version did.

Comment: Thank for the advice. This might not work if I reuse your snippet to update each feature?

Comment: I think I have to store `features[]` in `base64` like this https://starkandwayne.com/blog/bash-for-loop-over-json-array-using-jq/ to be able to deal with each item in another bash loop

Comment: There should be no need to use base64 encoding, which I think would only complicate things. You might find the `Q: How can a stream of JSON texts produced by jq be converted into a bash array of corresponding values?` useful in the jq FAQ: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. I am still interested in how to use the merge operator to produce what I want : "How can I merge two JSON objects?" in the FAQ. For the center of gravity, I was aware of that, I think that for convex shapes and uniformly distributed vertices, the average of the point is a good approximation.

Comment: There is a more sophisticated algorithm using quadtrees with a JS library here  at the Mapbox blog https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc
https://github.com/mapbox/polylabel