# Calculate center for each polygon in a list efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, postgresql-11

For my little data mining project on input data for finite element analysis I have exported the result of a SQL Query to a long python list of corners of elements (triangles, etc.). This this is some example data:

```
import numpy as np
#element_id, coordinates, data

corners = [(1, [-7.374797, -885.3285, 33.665], 1.0),
 (1, [-427.427897, -965.4985, 596.2296], 1.0), 
 (1, [-81.743197, -126.5385, 286.8912], 1.0),
 (2, [-22.248597, -878.7285, 111.239], 0.35), 
 (1, [-74.307097, -126.5385, 272.1152], 1.0),
 (2, [-74.307097, -126.5385, 286.8912], 0.35), 
 (2, [-81.743197, -126.5385, 286.8912], 0.35),  
 (3, [0.062103, -562.0245, 81.687], 1.25)]
```

Where the first value in each tuple in the list is the `id` of an element and the second value are the coordinates of a corner. For further processing, I need the center of each `element`, preferably in a numpy array, together with the data.

Since the table is quite long (~3Mio. Lines), im am looking for an efficient algorithm to calculate the the average of the coordinates of the corners for each element.

My plan so far has been to update the i-th element of a numpy array the following way:

```
x = np.zeros((3,4)) #initialize array
for c in corners:
    x[c[0],1:] = (x[c[0],0]*x[c[0],1:] + c[1])/(x[c[0],0]+1) #recursive formula for mean
    x[c[0],0] +=1
```

unfortunatlely there is several problems with this:

1. It's slow
2. I need to know the highest and lowest id (e.g. when I select just a subset) of the elements
3. I get `[0.,0.,0.,0.]`  lines if the id range has a gap.(e.g. when i have the element_ids 2,4,7...)

Is there any fast and flexible way of doing this, maybe with already existing numpy functions? What would be good data types to start with?
Is this better done directly in PostgreSQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I posted a similar question for geographical data. Beware that the center of gravity of polygons with holes might not be what you expect. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467305/computing-the-center-of-gravity-of-a-geojson-polygon-using-jq

Comment: Thanks. Fortunatley my faces are quite a bit simpler than yours, aka convex. But I have more of them...

Comment: I did not understand your comments about "highest and lowest id" and "gaps" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm am looking for an efficient algorithm to calculate the the average of the coordinates of the corners for each element.

Do it in Postgres right away:

```
SELECT element_id
     , ARRAY[avg(coordinates[1]), avg(coordinates[2]), avg(coordinates[3])]
FROM   tbl -- or your org. query here
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Should be *much* faster then first exporting un-aggregated data (many more rows) and then processing it.